# multi linear regression result interpretation on variable squared

Tags: regression

[image]

I have trouble interpreting the variable squared result on this regression.

for the information, my dependent variable is the gallons consumed by the aircraft.

The Leg mileage variable is the distance (miles) aircraft is flying from origin to destination and Leg_Sq is squared of Leg_Mileage.

The fleet age is the age of the aircraft and Age_Sq is squared of fleet age.

can you help me to interpret the variable  Leg_Sq also the Age_Sq? and give me a clear example.

**NOTE:** I know all the results of variables are statistically significant, I know the p-value less than 0.05 mean and I know I can use all the variables to predict gallons consumed. what I want to know is that how to interpret the variable squared, for example, fleet age squared has negative `coef -0.800`, how to interpret that if you connect it with the Fleet_age that has positive coef and what the impact with the dependent variable (gallons consumed)? you can give the example let's say 5 years old aircraft and the squared will be 25, so aircraft will increase more fuel until 25 years? I'm still confused about how to interpret this.

Leg_Sq = (Leg_Mileage)^2

Age_Sq = (Fleet Age)^2

Comment: Is $\text{Leg_sq}=(\text{Leg_mileage})^2?$ Ditto for the age variables?

Comment: yes, Leg_sq=(Leg_mileage)2

Comment: Write out the equation with the coefficient, and the question should start to answer itself. Ignoring the scientific notation, you would start with $\text{gallons}=-2.006+3.592(\text{loadFactor})+\dots$

Comment: so the variable squared like leg mileage and fleet age don't need to interpret 1 by 1? do I need to find the marginal effect from the variable squared?